# Unable to load most popups in Tor

Tags: bug

This issue only recently started happening, and only happens on Tor, but not on other browsers. But I can ask and answer questions, but I cannot flag, or click the trophy to see recent rep changes or click the inbox. It shows the window briefly then says Something went wrong. Please try again. And if I try to flag it says Unable to load popup - please try again. This happens on every site I've tried on.

Comment: Probably same as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393282/top-bar-navigation-partially-lost-when-accessing-from-tor-network-unable-to-po).

Comment: Confirmed, this is the same issue @ShadowTheGPTWizard linked.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Can you please dupehammer the question, per the staff comment above? There are four incorrect close votes to close this as blatantly off-topic, and even if I cast a dupe vote those four votes will override my reason.

Comment: @Sonic done. Funny it's now showing as if all four also closed as dupe. (Yeah, I know you reported that long time ago)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard It's [intentional design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339401/377214). As a binding voter, your reason will take precedence over others' reasons. The same happens when a mod closes for any reason - their reason will take precedence.