# Moderation tools are broken for Tor users

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, tor

Related to: [Top bar navigation partially lost when accessing from Tor network - unable to post answers or comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393282/384528)

Moderators are unable to perform most moderation actions when using Tor. Network requests necessary for the tools to work return 403 forbidden. As a result, I am unable to moderate my site.

Comment: Very related: [Why are many features not working on Tor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393717/241919)