# Why are many features not working on Tor?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, cloudflare, tor

[My question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393618/1370400) got closed as a duplicate as [another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393282/1370400). I'd have cast the duplicate vote myself but the bug the post is about prevented me from doing so. But anyway.

Apparently all the `GET` and `POST` requests are returning with `403 forbidden` messages. And a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393282/top-bar-navigation-partially-lost-when-accessing-from-tor-network-unable-to-po#comment1315355_393282) blames Cloudflare for this somehow. And something about an anti-bot system.

But I'm not sure what any of this really means, other than that in practice, it's keeping the site from working properly for us Tor users.

But what exactly is Cloudflare? Can someone explain to me what is going on like I'm five? And what technical changes caused this bug that did not used to occur occur now? And why does it only affect Tor users? Can someone give some technical insight and put it in layman's terms?

Edit: Here is something else I do not understand. What I think is happening based on my interpretation of the answer is that Stack Exchange was put behind Cloudflare to block illegitimate requests as a result of a DDoS attack or something. But my question is, why is Cloudflare blocking some types of requests (flag, vote to close, open inbox, open achievements) but not others (ask questions, edit posts)?

Another Edit: How is Cloudflare [blocking the JS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393717/why-are-many-features-not-working-on-tor#comment1320525_393717) files? Is it blocking them from being downloaded to the client, or is it blocking any requests that happen to be made from a JavaScript file? And how would it know?

Comment: From what I understand, SE tightened security using Cloudflare tools, it also has something to do with switching CDN (which host static files to reduce page load times) but didn't get how exactly. The tightened security results, naturally, in great many legit requests blocked, so SE twist the settings, and adding IP ranges to "allow lists" etc, and thus allowing most legit requests through. Why they won't do that for Tor, not sure, probably because too many spammers use it. Again, all of this might be wrong hence just a comment. Hopefully staff member who knows will come over and explain.

Comment: We have shared some info about this but it's been in comments. I've talked with some people internally and we'd like to share the explanation for this since we've seen some people thinking that this is intentional and we're trying to block ToR users, which is not the case. :)

Comment: Regarding the edit, what's being blocked are the JS files. Stack Exchange sites are built in a way that one can do the basic things even without JS at all, so that's why you can do the basic actions like asking or answering, even when all JS files are blocked.

Answer (score 22):

There are a couple of different things at play in this case, but since it involves Tor, I'll expand the answer to cover some other questions that were asked.

With the switch to Cloudflare as our [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), access to Stack Exchange network sites from Tor actually became faster due to Cloudflare's infrastructure on the Tor network. Cloudflare however treats Tor traffic with more scrutiny than normal internet traffic, as a lot of attacks originate from there.

To defend against [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) and other attacks from Tor, Cloudflare's web application firewall will flag some traffic from Tor as malicious, and they use various techniques to do this. One such example is cross referencing the source address to [FireHOL](https://iplists.firehol.org/). When Cloudflare suspects a request to be malicious, a [managed challenge](https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-firewall-rules/cloudflare-challenges/) is presented and if the challenge isn't solved, it will result in a block.

Another issue is Cloudflare's use of [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) on the Tor network. This causes some things to simply not work due to our application not supporting IPv6 yet. The most visible manifestation of this is the top bar not working.

We've implemented as many workarounds as possible without outright blocking IPv6 traffic as it will take time to implement IPv6 support. In the interim, users can try adding `ORPort 443 IPv4Only` to their [torrc](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13037/how-to-config-the-torrc-file) file to try and force [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) connections through Tor, but this still has mixed results from our testing.

Comment: Adding `ORPort 443 IPv4Only` to my `torrc` file worked, but only on Meta, not on other sites, odd.

Comment: Possible explanation: Cloudflare is often used for caching of static content, if you've already cached that content then you won't get the related issue.