# Stack Exchange inbox messages don't work with the Tor browser

Tags: bug, tor

When I try to check out my recent messages or recent achievements using the top right buttons I can't. It simply says "Something went wrong. please try again."
I guess Cloudflare is not supporting Tor browser users?

[image: Inbox icon and error: Something went wrong. Please try again.]

[image]

So my question differs from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393717/why-are-many-features-not-working-on-tor)
ok so here are few difference highlights from the other question

> Why are many features not working on Tor?

- that question was asked about 5 days ago while mine is happening today, that problem is maybe already been fixed.
- that question is addressing a different type of bug in which im not facing using tor, i simply don't get a "403 forbidden" error, my problem is the website itself doesn't work with Tor browser it might not related to the CF anyways.
- the answer to that question is not related to what im asking right now cause these are buttons not working not 403 error so it doesn't work
- that question also addressing a general issue while im reporting a specific BUG with pictures  and screenshots.
- the error "Something went wrong. please try again." is nowhere being written in that question, so that question doesn't relate to this one

and please again whoever read this please don't report this post as a duplicate since it isn't, and this is trolling, you might gain more trophies or score or more views by reporting this as a duplicate idk , but by doing that , youre preventing staff to view the actual report , so again please don't this isn't related to that old post .

<sub>And try not to close this question. Please let some staff view it, because there is a chance that it could be fixed.</sub>

Comment: @Glorfindel sir i appreciate the edit that you have done , but i stand my ground the responsible person behind CloudFlare doesn't like people who use Tor browser because he is being fed by radical governors

Comment: You probably have a good reason to use Tor, but many trolls and hackers use it as well to make it harder to track their malicious behaviour. Therefore, please don't expect everything on the Internet to work when using Tor ... it has nothing to do with "radical governors".

Comment: @Glorfindel of curse, but what if im living in a country that does not allow me to use internet? and block the internet ? and i said it before , and as i know Tor browser has made by US government for these type of users am i right? what ever if you look up into my account you could see that im a peaceful user who wants to use internet

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ idk man , these radicals are spending money to restrict our access to internet, thats all ....

Comment: We don't doubt your intentions, not at all. But it doesn't help questioning the intentions of CloudFlare, Stack Exchange, or any other site that you're using.

Comment: @Glorfindel last time i have asked somehow same question , but that one was different but it has fixed immediately after my post , it seems like CloudFlare is customizable , but its default setting are to ruin other users whom using VPN or Tor browser , because their government is a dictatorship who don't want them to access internet, thats obvious they're spending money on jerk companies like CF to restrict access of their own people to internet ( sorry for Jerk term but ...)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is not a duplicate post, these questions are kind of similar but yet they are different, this post is closed by your false report sir

Comment: I think the better duplicate is this one, which reports the exact same issue with the top bar for Tor users: [Top bar navigation partially lost when accessing from Tor network - unable to post answers or comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393282)

Comment: The question was closed by multiple people identifying that your "problem" is choosing Tor instead of a supported browser. Nobody cares what **you are** aiming to do, they care about what **someone might be** aiming to do via Tor, and the risk is just not worth it. It isn't personal, and your edits and responses are beyond rude.

Comment: "*youre preventing staff to view the actual report*" staff already knew and acknowledged the issue about Tor. They're still trying to adjust and fix any real possible issues. To be honest, this post is a duplicate and doesn't really add any insights for the developers to troubleshoot further.